# Haskell list frozen

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and playing around trying to understand a few things. If I do the following I receive a problem:

```
list1 = [1..]
list2 = [x | x <- list1, x <= 4]
print list2
```

which returns `[1,2,3,4`. There isn't an end bracket on it, so it is as if the list is loading or frozen. Here is how it looks:

```
Prelude> print list2
[1,2,3,4
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Pretend you're GHCI. Your user gives you an infinite list and asks you to find all the values in that list that are less than or equal to 4. How would you go about doing it? (Keep in mind that you don't know that the list is in order.)

Comment: Ahh, yeah that makes sense. Is there a way to deal with infinite lists and conditions like this?

Comment: You can `take 4` elements from `list1` (literally `list2 = take 4 list1`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You* know that the list is monotonically increasing, but Haskell does not. Use `takeWhile`, instead of a list comprehension, so that `list1` can stop being evaluated once you find a value greater than 4.

```
> list1 = [1..]
> list2 = takeWhile (<= 4) list1
> print list2
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that `list1` is still being computed, and for each new element of the `list1` predicate `x <= 4` is applied, which is `false` for every `x` after `4`.

So, in summary:

To printout `list2` interpreter need to compute `list1` and check each list item that it is `<= 4`, and because `list1` is infinite computation of it must take infinite time.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking every element in `list1` and, for each one that's less than 4, making it a entry in `list2`. Look how many elements you have in `list1`.